# How to make a window come up on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, recaptcha

So basically my goal is to code my own ReCaptcha. To make that possible, I'd like a window to come up once I clicked a button to send a form or something like this. In best case it looks [like this](https://cdn.wpforms.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Example-of-v2-reCAPTCHA.png), but with my own content inside. Is it possible to do this with just one js-script, or with adding a few divs?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use jquery modal.

check the following link https://jquerymodal.com/

official docs can be found at

https://jqueryui.com/dialog/